# I declare a variable in C# and cannot use it inside of the switch statement

Tags: c#, variables, scope, switch-statement, local

Consider this C# code:

```
string gr = comboBox1.ValueMember;
decimal sum;
try
{
    decimal rite = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
    decimal left = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    string swr = "Please enter REAL a number, can be with decimals";
    label2.Text = swr;
}

switch (gr)
{
    case "X":
        sum = 12M;
        break;
    case "/":
        break;
    case "*":
        break;
    case "-":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

answerText.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
```

If I give the decimal `sum` a value during the switch statement, it will popup with an error statement saying:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'sum'

I'm a newbie at C# so this might sound stupid saying it. It looks like I ALREADY set the value of sum inside the `switch` statement. I tried putting the same `sum = 12M;` in all of the other case statements, but that doesn't seem to help.

By the way, im also having problems modifying other variables outside of the switch statement - EX. rite, left;

Comment: Did you put it inside the `default` as well?  Either way, you need to initialize it through ALL code paths.  The easiest way to do this is to change the declaration at the top to be something like: `decimal sum = 0.0m`.

Comment: An aside: It is [generally a bad idea](http://www.ironshay.com/post/Please-Use-TryParse-and-Avoid-Parse2bTryCatch.aspx) to use a try/catch with a cast in order to parse string input.  Consider using [`Decimal.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 7):

If `gr` is NOT equal to "X" `sum` has no value. The compiler is warning you for that.

Answer (score 3):

Only `instance variables` get default values, so a local variable like `sum`, has to be `initialized`, for it to be used somewhere else. Since there is the possibility that it will not get assigned anything, the compiler raises an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting the value of sum for ONE condition and hence it won't always be assigned at the point when you are trying to convert it to string. Try declaring it as `decimal sum = 0.0;`.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler detected that a path of execution exists in which the variable won't be assigned. If `gr` is anything other than `X` you will be using an unassigned value after the switch statement.

You can simply add the initial value to the declaration:

```
decimal sum = 0m;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the variable sum is only assigned if the switch statement hits the "X" case.  To fix this, set a default value by doing the following at the top:

```
decimal sum = 0m;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign default value to it when declaring and you won't get error:

```
decimal sum = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

At declaration you should use this:

```
decimal sum=0m;
```

the compiler doesn't ensure that the first case will hold so sum may still be used without assigning